# Show a comparative bar graph based on dates Tableau

Tags: date, tableau-api, gantt-chart

The details for the question are in this link.

[Details of the question](http://community.tableau.com/thread/187693)

Sorry, didn't wanted to duplicate the data.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps here:

First you'll need to union the tables together. Add a field (just a string) to indicate whether the times are planned or actual. The SQL might look like this:

```
SELECT ID,
       TASK,
       START_DATE,
       END_DATE,
       "Planned" AS TYPE
FROM PLANNED
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       TASK,
       START_DATE,
       END_DATE,
       "Actual" AS TYPE
FROM ACTUAL;
```

You'll end up with a table like:

```
+----+------+-------+------+---------+
| ID | TASK | START | END  | TYPE    |
+----+------+-------+------+---------+
| 1  | 1    | 8/12  | 8/19 | Planned |
| 1  | 1    | 8/14  | 8/23 | Actual  |
| 2  | 2    | 8/21  | 8/23 | Planned |
| 2  | 2    | 8/24  | 8/29 | Actual  |
| .. | ...  | ...   | ...  | ...     |
+----+------+-------+------+---------+
```

Bring this table into Tableau. You'll need to make a calculated field to calculate the length of the task.

```
DATEDIFF('day', START_DATE, END_DATE)
```

Then create a Gantt chart. Drag that calculated field (length) into size. Start date goes in the columns. Task and Type go in the rows.